# Adjust UI for multi screen size on Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, size, screen, resolution

I just started learning Android Game Programming on Unity3D.

I want to create a Main menu with an ImageButton. However, when I rotate the device to landscape mode, the button is distorted.

Could you help me to resolve this problem? Thank you!

Below are some my screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Comment: I use Canvas Scaler as this tutorial but it doesn't work.

Comment: it should work like that

Comment: So, how do I make the image not distorted?

Comment: follow Everts answer

Answer (score 1):

Image component has a Preserve Aspect toggle. It will prevent the stretching of the sprite to fill the whole rect.

Comment: Do you have it ticked on Panel or Button? Make sure you have the tick on the Image component that contains the arrow image. Else you have a bug but I doubt it since you 'd be the only one.

Comment: I ticked on Button as the image on my question

Comment: This is not the usual behaviour, even more considering you have all anchors in the middle. It could be you have restriction on the orientation and something is forcing it while you rotate.

Comment: Can you guide me more details? I have tried many tutorials but none of them work for me

Comment: it is difficult to help considering that for your problem as described, my answer should solve. It means either you are doing something else or your project is corrupted. Not much I can do to help. At least, nothing I know of.

Comment: Ok. I think I found out my problem. The issue happen when I used Unity Remote 5 for debug my app. If I build and run my app, it work properly. Thanks for your help ^^